# Android Camera.Parameter.SCENE_MODE_BARCODE doesn't work for most devices

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, barcode, barcode-scanner

When we try to set camera parameter to scan BarCode, I'd like to set scene mode to have a better performance.

I saw this code

```
    Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
    cameraParameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_BARCODE);
    camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
```

But this keeps throwing exception with message, "setParameter failed".

Answer (score 2):

You can check if this sceneMode is supported on your device and apply it if it's the case with :

```
 Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
 List<String> sceneModes = cameraParameters.getSupportedSceneModes();

    if (sceneModes != null){
        if (sceneModes.contains(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_BARCODE)) {
            cameraParameters.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_BARCODE);
        }            
    }
    camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
```

Comment: This is a very good way to avoid the exception. I wanted to know why SCENE_MODE_BARCODE does not work for most devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
```

And you can use `parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()` and choose which one is best for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Scene mode and focus are separate parameters, providing continuous picture feedback and auto focus.